# Why don't Log outputs end up in Bags? Can I force them to?

Tags: ros, rosbag, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a big fan of rosbags. Right now I am doing a series of pretty complex tests on some mobile robots. I like to bag everything for each test, so that I can go back and review what happened to catch bugs. Rqt_bag's visualization capabilities make debugging certain aspects of my system extremely easy. However, I am continually frustrated that Log information produced by calls to ROS_ERROR(), ROS_INFO(), ROS_DEBUG(), etc. does not appear to be stored in my bag files. I can see that rosout has messages publish in it similar to:

- header
- level:  8
- name: /PelicanMMS
- file: /asctec/PelicanMMS/PelicanROS/src/VTOL...
- function: startHandler
- line:  38
- topics

This can point me to the exact origin of one of my debug calls, but it does not contain the actual text of the call! I know that the text from my log calls can be found in the generated log files, or captured with rqt_console; but, I want the logging text stored in my bag. My questions are:

Is there some system setting or configuration that I could specify to make the text logging information get bagged?
If this is impossible, is there a simple work around?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187040/why-don%27t-log-outputs-end-up-in-bags?-can-i-force-them-to?/) by [Carter12s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5109/carter12s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you're running into this bug: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/226

In short, your log output is there, but rqt_bag isn't displaying it due to a bug.

A couple of things to try:

- Upgrade to a newer version of rqt_bag
- Use rosbag play to play back your log files into rqt_console.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carter12s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5109/carter12s/) on 2014-07-21**:
That is it exactly! The bug is with rqt_bag; I can publish from rqt_bag into rqt_console and see the 'msg' field, but rqt_bag does not display it internally. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hmm, this should be possible with the standard tools. The log messages should be on the /rosout topic, which has message type rosgraph_msgs/Log. One of the fields of Log is "msg", which contains the text of the call to ROS_ERROR() and friends. Using roscpp_tutorials/talker as an example:

(in one terminal):

```
rosrun roscpp_tutorials talker
```

(in another terminal, simultaneously):

```
rostopic echo rosout/msg
```

this will print the text of the calls to the ROS_whatever() macros

to toss these Log messages into a bag with your other topics, just add the "rosout" topic to the list of topics you're passing to "rosbag record":

```
rosbag record topic1 topic2 rosbag [...]
```

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2